# SwiftUI NavigationLink shows as highlighted when going back from destination view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I got a `NavigationLink` inside a `Form` (screenshot 1). When I click, the navigation goes to a detail page (screenshot 2). When I go back by using either the back button or swipe gesture, the `NavigationLink` turns into a highlighted state (screenshot 3).

See below my code.

How should I fix this issue?
Thanks.

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]
[image: screenshot 3]

Home (where the first navigationlink is):

```
NavigationView {
                    // Content
                    VStack {
                        // Navigation to profileview
                        NavigationLink(destination: ProfileView(showing: self.$profileClicked).environmentObject(self.user),
                                       isActive: self.$profileClicked) {}
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            Button(action: {self.profileClicked.toggle()}) {
                                Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Profileview (screenshot 1):

```
VStack {
        
        // ...
        
        List {
            Section {
                NavigationLink(destination: AccountInfoView().environmentObject(self.user)) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(Color("main"))
                        Text("Account information")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        Spacer()
        
        // ...
    }
    .navigationTitle("Profile")
}
```

Accountview (2nd screenshot)

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Form {
            HStack {
                Text("ID:")
                    .padding(8)
                Spacer()
                Text(self.user.id)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                    .lineLimit(1)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Email:")
                    .padding(8)
                Spacer()
                Text(self.user.email)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .lineLimit(1)
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Account")
}
```

Comment: Provided code snapshot works fine with Xcode 12.0 / iOS 14, so your issue is either in different code or due to other env.

Comment: Do you have more than one NavigationView? Or do you use this from a UINavigationController? Or do you present it as a sheet?

Comment: 1 navigationview, with 1 navigationlink to this profileview, and from there the navigationlink to the detail. No sheet, just a new page with navlink destination. @pawello2222

Comment: As Asperi said, your example is not reproducible. Please try to include the full view hierarchy (not the full code, just the hierarchy - eg. we don't even see a Form).

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Added the code you asked for. @pawello2222

Comment: @TobiasHesselink did you ever find a solution to this? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: @AndrewEbling Excuse me for my late response.
This was a SwiftUI bug itself, i did not found a solution for SwiftUI 1.0. Maybe in the 2.0 or even the current SwiftUI 3.0 this bug is fixed (which i think it is).

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.onAppear` on `List` and set `selectionStyle` to `none`

```
List{}.onAppear {
  UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none
}
```

make sure to have everything wrapped up in an `NavigationView`

Comment: Didn't work for me. Don't know fore sure, but I think the 'List' isn't appearing again, because it's in the navigationview it's stack...

Comment: do you have everything wrapped up in NavigationView

Comment: The profileview is a destination from an other navigationlink so I don't use a new navigationview because it's already in one from the first navlink

Comment: i see, might seem weird but try to apply selection style function on the main List

Comment: it did work for me tho, tested it few times i think something is missing

Comment: Tried many times. If i print something in the .onAppear, it works. But the code for UITable.... = .none isn't working.

Comment: Weird please make sure its on List bracket

Comment: Tried a lot, nothing worked. I'll wait for another answer. Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

We observed the same issue. Unhighlighting of cells is not working if the List is added inside the VStack.

The following snippet is not working on iOS 14.

```
  UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none
```

The way we were able to fix it is by using LazyVStack.

We migrated from hierarchy `VStack->List` to `VStack->ScrollView->LazyVStack->ForEach`